# rails, selection from dropdown menu does not trigger a different filter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of events which i want to filter acordingly to a selection in a dropdown menu. But there is no action triggered when i select a different item, I just end up with the default on. The view seems to be working, i have the table displayed and the box with the items as well, just the selection does not change anything. I am guessing my selection does not trigger an event, so that the part in the .coffee is faulty. here the relevant code, i hope somebody can help:

events.rb

```
scope :men, -> { where(team_id: 1) }
scope :women, -> { where(team_id: 2) }
scope :juniors, -> { where(team_id: 3) }
```

events_controller.rb

```
def index
    @events = Event.where("startdate >= ?", Date.today)
               .order("startdate, starttime")

    @events = apply_type_filter(@events)
end

def apply_type_filter(relation)
   case params[:filter]
   when "Men" 
      relation.men
   when "Women" 
      relation.women 
   when "Juniors"
      relation.juniors
   else
      relation
   end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="left">
<%= form_tag events_path, :method => 'get' do %>  
    <%= select_tag "filter", options_for_select([ "Alle", "Men", "Women", "Juniors" ], params[:filter]), class: 'my_filter' %>
<% end %>
```

events.js:

```
$(function(){
 $('select.my_filter').on('change', function(){
  alert($(this).val())
  $(this).closest('form').submit()
 })
})
```

the following html code is generated when i run the page:

```
<div class="left">
<input type="text" class="filter" id="events-filter-input" placeholder="Termine filtern" />
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/events" method="get"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /></div>  
    <select class="my_filter" id="filter" name="filter"><option value="Alle">Alle</option>
<option value="Men">Men</option>
<option value="Women">Women</option>
<option value="Juniors">Juniors</option></select>
</form></div>
```

if it helps the jacasvript code as well:

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from example.com/assets/…
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker.js
//= require_tree .
```

application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Thank you for your help. As an addition i would like to make that a User can define which selection should be shown for him first. How would i go about that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be an issue with the DOM loading. You could try one of two approaches:
1) Copy the JS in `event.js` and put it in  tags at the bottom of your `Index` page.
2) Remove `event.js` all-together and just add `:onchange => "this.form.submit()` to your `select_tag`.
These are rough and ready methods that have worked for me in similar situations.